# 2007 Mercury Montego Premier Various Electrical Issues

Tags: electrical, ignition, wiring, lights, window

Recently purchased an 07 Mercury Montego Premier for a secondary vehicle/work vehicle. Engine seems to be great, but there are various minor issues that just annoy me.

Driver's side window works, but not the auto function in either direction. Passenger side front window doesn't work at all, from it's own button nor the driver's side button. Is this a wiring issue or does it need a new motor? Or, how do you determine the issue?

The passenger side dome/interior light turns on and off when you wiggle the key/ignition. Again, wiring? How do you determine?

Cruise control works sometimes and doesn't work other times.

Bulb for fuel in instrument cluster goes dim, but illuminates fully with a smack on the dash.

Driver side heated seat isn't working. When you press the button the two little red lights illuminate (low/high heat indicator I assume), but they immediately go out when button is released. Passenger side works. Press the button once and both lights illuminate, press again for one light/low then again for off.

Traction control button will illuminate within the button and SOMTIMES a light within the instrument cluster. Why sometimes for the cluster light?

How does one determine the culprit for these issues?

Comment: Most of these issues are diagnosed with a multimeter and a lot of experience on how to use it.

Comment: Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For passenger window: access window motor. Find wire diagram for windows. Do you have battery voltage on positive terminal when operating window switch in the designated position found in diagram? If yes, the motor may be bad. If no you have a break in the circuit somewhere from the switch to the motor.    The auto function may just need calibrated. You may find the procedure online.    For cluster, again using wire diagram, check for appropriate voltages at cluster connector. If all is good see if it uses bulbs or led. If bulbs are good, you may have to replace cluster or send it in for repair.    Cruise control: again with wire diagram check voltages at all points required. With ohmmeter check the traction control switch for proper operation. Also when ever checking voltages also means checking for good grounds.